# What type of Https certificate needed for Serviceworker

Tags: https, service-worker

I have a *website* that works offline using **service worker**. I heard that, to make it live need a proper **https** certificate. How to get one https certificate? its free? Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 grades of TLS certificates:

1. Domain Authority
2. Organizational Authority
3. Enterprise Authority

They are all valid certificates, they just require a higher level of authentication to obtain. Most sties just need a DA certificate, which is validated via the whois e-mail. The other two take more vetting.

As far as SNI or not SNI that does not matter either.

All that matters is you have the TLS certificate to create that wrapper of encryption around the data packets.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a certificate from the [Letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) organisation. It's free and reliable. I can recommend it.